# Java Rectangle Program

Tags: java

I made a program to displace a random number of rectangles on the screen with buttons to make fewer or more with either doubles or halves the number of rectangles. Then I was asked to modify the program to add a slider instead of buttons to the program to control the amount of rectangle on the screen. I am having some trouble.

I am getting a few errors. My professor insists on using IntelliJ IDE for the development environment, which I am not too familiar with. It's asking me to move package c16 and also to make public class Random Rectangles to main or not public any help would be good.

```
    package c16;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JSlider;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

    public class RandomRectangles extends JFrame {

    private int rectangle_count=1;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                RandomRectangles r = new RandomRectangles();
                r.setTitle("Rectangles");
                r.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
                r.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public RandomRectangles()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 500, 1);

        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                rectangle_count = slider.getValue();
                RandomRectangles.this.repaint();
            }
        });

    /*
    On clicking SHRINK(FEWER),
     half the number of rectangles in the RectangleArea
     with different co-ordinates.
     */

        JPanel rectangleArea = new JPanel()
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //in-built function.
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                /*Get the random co-ordinates for Rectangle.*/
                for(int i=0;i<rectangle_count;i++){
                    int a= (int)Math.floor(random.nextDouble()*getWidth());
                    int b=(int)Math.floor(random.nextDouble()*getHeight());
                    int c = (int)Math.floor(random.nextDouble()*(getWidth()-a));
                    int d = (int)Math.floor(random.nextDouble()*(getHeight()-b));
                    g.drawRect(a,b,c,d);
                }
            }

        };
      /*Add the buttons and the panel to the BorderLayout
      so that they are visible for demo.
       */
        add(slider,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(rectangleArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. In general the directory structure and the package structure should match. So this class should be in a directory named `c16`.

Comment: can you please share the errors you are getting

Comment: the error i get when i run the code is java: class RandomRectangles is public, should be declared in a file named RandomRectangles.java. the ide tells me to rename RandomRectangles to main